# What's the Perl equivalent of Python's enumerate?

Tags: python, perl

I'm looking for a function in Perl 5 that works similarly to Python's [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in. It would return a list of references to arrays, where each array is `[$index, $element]`:

```
@a = ("a", "b", "c");
@b = enumerate @a;
# @b = ([0, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"])
```

[List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) and [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) don't seem to have this function. Is there another module that does?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `map`, like this

```
my @data = qw / a b c /;
my @enumeration = map [ $_, $data[$_] ], 0 .. $#data;
```

Comment: I didn't know `map` could accept a block without curly braces like that.

Comment: @Flimm: It will take either a *block* or an *expression*. Take a look at [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).The block is strictly necessary only when you need to write multiple statements (such as the common `map { chomp; $_ } <$fh>`) or to disambiguate the call. In practice it can be a help to making your code readable. Here, I omitted the braces because the expression already has square brackets to delimit it.

Answer (score 12):

`enumerate` returns an iterator, not a list, so you should really be asking for an iterator.

---

In Perl 5.12.0 and up, you can use [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) to iterate over arrays:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.012;

my @a = qw(foo bar baz);

while (my ($i, $v) = each @a) {
    say "$i -> $v";
}

__END__
0 -> foo
1 -> bar
2 -> baz
```

However, you should be very careful when using `each`; [some people even discourage its use altogether](http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/2014/04/do-not-use-each.html).

Comment: `each` not being reentrant is a pretty big flaw with it, but it's good to know this option.

Comment: Yes, this is a great feature.  I use it with `foreach`. We often need both index and value.  But it doesn't seem to be known.

Comment: @zdim I just found out about it last week!

Comment: @zdim I doubt you can use `each` with `foreach`

Comment: @cl0ne Yeah, now I am not sure what I meant with that comment!  (I wish I could edit them...)  It was probably about navigating things like AoH or such?  How would one combine `for` and `each`?

Comment: @zdim I couldn't come up with anything better than `my @arr = qw(a b c d); for(; my ($i, $v) = each(@arr) ;) { say "$i -> $v"; }` which is definitely worse than the same thing written with `while` >_<

Comment: @cl0ne Right, that'd be terrible.  (I don't use `for(; ...)` ... can't imagine what I meant :(

Answer (score 7):

Perl doesn't have a built-in function to do that but it's easy to roll your own.

Using `map`:

```
my @a = qw(a b c);
my $i = 0;
my @b = map [$i++, $_], @a; # ([0, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'c'])
```

As of v5.20, Perl's new slice syntax does something similar:

```
my @a = qw(a b c);
my @b = %a[0..$#a]; # (0, 'a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c')
```

That slice syntax returns a list of index/value pairs but it's a flat list. The pairs aren't grouped into nested arrays. If that's important to your application you can use the pairmap function from List::Util to do it:

```
use List::Util qw(pairmap);
my @a = qw(a b c);
my @b = pairmap {[$a, $b]} %a[0..$#a]; # ([0, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'c'])
```

Comment: I always delight in the philosophy of *TMTOWTDI*, but surely the use of `List::Util::pairmap` on top of an index/value array slice is just a curiosity? At present I believe that index/value and key/value slices should have been designed to return an array of pairs, as it is much simpler to flatten a list than to pair it up.

Comment: @Borodin: I don't understand your question. I've updated the answer to more clearly illustrate the purpose of using `pairmap`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm just saying that a solution that uses a very new feature of Perl together with a core library function, and still ends up being longer than your simple `map` statement, must be theoretical musing and not a practical suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [List::Enumerate](http://search.cpan.org/~spurin/List-Enumerate-0.005/lib/List/Enumerate.pm) module.

```
use List::Enumerate qw(enumerate);
@a = ("a", "b", "c");
@b = map { [ $_->index, $_->item ] } enumerate(@a);
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much of a reason to use [`List::Enumerate`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Enumerate) here

Comment: I agree with Borodin. It's just a lot of overhead.

Comment: [`List::Enumerate`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Enumerate) has become less useful since version 12 of Perl 5, which allows the use of `each` on arrays. The example in the module's documentation can be written with just `print "$i $name\n" while ($i, $name) = each @list;`

Comment: @Borodin `each` is not re-entrant though, a gotcha that I would rather avoid.

Answer (score -2):

```perl
sub enumerate(&@) {
    local *f = shift;
    my @array = @_;
    my @ret;
    my $pkg = caller;
    for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < @array ; $i++ ) {
        no strict 'refs';
        local *{ $pkg . '::a' } = \$i;
        local *{ $pkg . '::b' } = \$array[$i];
        push @ret, f( $i, $array[$i] );
    }
    @ret;
}
my @tmp = enumerate { ($a, $b) } 'a'..'z';
say "@tmp";
```